# UWP File Copy destination does not take encryption into account

Tags: encryption, uwp

I have a UWP app (which I developed under Win10 Family with Visual Studio 2017 C #) which creates a text file in the myapp \ LocalState directory.
When I want to copy this file to another directory I have a message telling me that the destination does not take encryption into account (normal Win10 family has no encryption capability).
It is as if this file would encrypted. When I try to decrypt with Cipher I have a message "incorrect parameter".
What's this ?

Comment: When I tried to copy a file from localFolder to Pictures library under Win10 Family account, it worked well. So can you show the code snippet about how you create a text file and copy this file?

Answer (score 0):

It has always worked properly until now. This is a new problem. Now I have error messages 0x80073CF6 0x80070199 0x80070032 ...
I think there are corrupted files or registers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by working around.
I store my data files in "Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary".